# Collision detection between objects in Tiled and a Sprite's bounding box in cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, collision, tiled

I am trying to make a platform game for the iphone, using cocos2d and Tiled (for the maps).
All of the tutorials i've seen on the net are using Layers in Tiled to do collision detection.
I want to use objects to do that...not Layers. 
With objects you can create custom shapes that can give a better 'reality' into the game.
To give an example of what i mean : 
[image]

I've drawn the ground as a background and created an object layer on top.
I want to detect player collision with that, instead of the background tile.

Now using the most famous tutorial out there : http://www.raywenderlich.com/15230/how-to-make-a-platform-game-like-super-mario-brothers-part-1
I am trying to rewrite checkForAndResolveCollisions method to check collisions for the objects instead.
The problem is that in Tiled the coordinates system is different than cocos2d. Tiled starts from top left corner, cocos2d from bottom left corner....and not only that...I noticed that the width and height of the object properties in Tiled (probably) dont correspond to the same in iphone devices.
The above rectangle has properties:

[image]

its w/h is 480/128 in tiled (for retina devices) which means its probably huge inside the map if i keep them like this. My guess is i have to divide this by 2.
So far i got this:

```
-(void)checkForAndResolveObjCollisions:(Player *)p {

    CCTiledMapObjectGroup *objectGroup = [map objectGroupNamed:@"Collision"];
    NSArray* tiles = [objectGroup objects];

    CGFloat x, y, wobj, hobj;
    for (NSDictionary *dic in tiles) {
        CGRect pRect = [p collisionBoundingBox]; //3
        x = [[dic valueForKey:@"x"] floatValue];
        y = [[dic valueForKey:@"y"] floatValue];
        wobj = [[dic valueForKey:@"width"] floatValue];
        hobj = [[dic valueForKey:@"height"] floatValue];

        CGPoint position = CGPointMake(x, y);
        CGPoint objPos = [self tileForPosition:position];
        CGRect tileRect = CGRectMake(objPos.x, objPos.y, wobj/2, hobj/2);

            if (CGRectIntersectsRect(pRect, tileRect)) {
                CCLOG(@"INTERSECT");
                CGRect intersection = CGRectIntersection(pRect, tileRect);
                NSUInteger tileIndx = [tiles indexOfAccessibilityElement:dic];
                if (tileIndx == 0) {
                    //tile is directly below player
                    p.desiredPosition = ccp(p.desiredPosition.x, p.desiredPosition.y + intersection.size.height);
                    p.velocity = ccp(p.velocity.x, 0.0);
                    p.onGround = YES;
                } else if (tileIndx == 1) {
                    //tile is directly above player
                    p.desiredPosition = ccp(p.desiredPosition.x, p.desiredPosition.y - intersection.size.height);
                    p.velocity = ccp(p.velocity.x, 0.0);
                } else if (tileIndx == 2) {
                    //tile is left of player
                    p.desiredPosition = ccp(p.desiredPosition.x + intersection.size.width, p.desiredPosition.y);
                } else if (tileIndx == 3) {
                    //tile is right of player
                    p.desiredPosition = ccp(p.desiredPosition.x - intersection.size.width, p.desiredPosition.y);
                } else {
                    if (intersection.size.width > intersection.size.height) {
                        //tile is diagonal, but resolving collision vertially
                        p.velocity = ccp(p.velocity.x, 0.0);
                        float resolutionHeight;
                        if (tileIndx > 5) {
                            resolutionHeight = -intersection.size.height;
                            p.onGround = YES;
                        } else {
                            resolutionHeight = intersection.size.height;
                        }

                        p.desiredPosition = ccp(p.desiredPosition.x, p.desiredPosition.y + resolutionHeight );

                    } else {
                        float resolutionWidth;
                        if (tileIndx == 6 || tileIndx == 4) {
                            resolutionWidth = intersection.size.width;
                        } else {
                            resolutionWidth = -intersection.size.width;
                        }
                        p.desiredPosition = ccp(p.desiredPosition.x + resolutionWidth , p.desiredPosition.y);

                    }
                }
            }
     //   }
    }
    p.position = p.desiredPosition; //8
}




- (CGPoint)tileForPosition:(CGPoint)p

{
    NSInteger x = (NSInteger)(p.x / map.tileSize.width);
    NSInteger y = (NSInteger)(((map.mapSize.height * map.tileSize.width) - p.y) / map.tileSize.width);
    return ccp(x, y);

}
```

I am getting the object x,y,w,h and try to convert them to cocos2d dimensions and sizes.

The above translates to this:

```
Dimens: 480.000000, 128.000000
Coord: 0.000000, 40.000000
```

Basically its a mess. And its not working .....at all. The player just falls right through.
I am surprised noone has done collision detection based on objects before...unless i am wrong.

Does anyone know if this can be done or how it can be done ?
Kinda what he does here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=2_KB4tOTH6w#t=30

Sorry for the long post.
Thanks for any answers in advance.